# Java Thread: Specify function to Call in Thread's run function

Tags: java, multithreading

I wonder if it's possible define function that will be called in `Thread's run`. It can be done by using if statement but is there a better way to do so?

a possible solution

```
public class WorkerThread extends Thread {
    private String functionToCall = null;

    public WorkerThread(String functionToCall) {
        this.functionToCall = functionToCall;
    }

    public void run() {
        if (functionToCall.equals("func1"))
            func1();
        else if (functionToCall.equals("func2"))
            func2();
    }

    private void func1() {
    }

    private void func2() {
    }

}
```

Comment: You could use reflection to do this:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/160970/how-do-i-invoke-a-java-method-when-given-the-method-name-as-a-string

Comment: Why don't you just implement two different `Thread` instances?

Comment: may be for writing less code?

Comment: fane89 maybe you would want to post your comment as an answer

Comment: One class should only solve one problem. If you have two problems you should not mix them up. This principle is called [Separation of concerns](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Separation_of_concerns).

Comment: yes you are right and I'm already trying to Create a class which has different functions in it that provides different type of data using webservice. So I want my data provider to be only one class. By the way link is broken

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Java reflection provides a way of calling a method by name. The tutorial is available here: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/reflect/.

Answer (score 5):

Yes, pass in a different `Runnable` object to the constructor, depending on what you want to run. Like this:

```
new Thread(myRunnable1);
```

or

```
new Thread(myRunnable2);
```

Then you don't need the `WorkerThread` class.

Comment: @ismail, I would actually go with this answer. Mine is an answer to the your exact question, but this is a much better technique. I would recommend avoiding reflection if possible.

Answer (score 0):

It is correct but I recommend do this using [interfaces](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/concepts/interface.html).